# How to disable CORS today with Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, cors, firefox-quantum

I tried setting this flag to false, but it doesn't work...

security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

I'm using Firefox Quantum 61.0.1

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to access files from your filesystem? Or are you just trying to disable the same origin policy for the WWW? Why not build a sensible development environment which implements CORS properly?

Comment: I'm trying to access a service hosted at my computer

Comment: What sort of service. An HTTP service?

Comment: Yes. I tried adding custom headers at App.config (C# .Net) unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because the `fileuri` configuration section is specifically for File URIs, and you are using an HTTP URI.

You need to either:

- Load the HTML page your script is running in from the *same origin*
- Figure out why your attempt to enable CORS failed
- Install a browser extension to fake CORS support (these tend to be unreliable (especially when a preflight request is needed) and risks you opening yourself up to security issues on the WWW).